# OpenCart 3.0.2.0 - how to change sort order of search results & disable search in descriptions?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

OpenCart 3.0.2.0 + Journal2 theme.

Problem: when using the search function, the results are sorted by "Default" sort order.

How can I change it to sort by "Name A-Z" (ascending)?

I've found a couple of solutions on SO, but they relate to OC 2.x, not 3.x, and they didn't work when I tried to implement them.

Also, as a bonus, if anyone knows how to disable the "Search in product descriptions" by default, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: if you have not complete your development then i will recommenced you to install 3.0.2.1b its cover all issue of 3.0.2.0

Comment: 1.) We have completed development, and there are too many customizations to start from scratch, for this one feature. 2.) The Release Notes for 3.0.2.1b state "Non production Beta Do not use on a live web site." ... sooooo not going to risk it.

Answer (score 1):

**For sort by "Name A-Z" (ascending)**

Got to this path

**catalog/controller/product/product.php**

change code

**Original Code**

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.sort_order';
}
```

**Change Only else part**

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'pd.name';
}
```

[image]
**For disable the "Search in product descriptions with 2 way.**

**Solution 1**

remove or hide descriptions checkbox, check image below

[image]

**Solution 2**

Got to this path

**catalog/controller/product/search.php**

Original Code

```
$filter_data = array(
    'filter_name'         => $search,
    'filter_tag'          => $tag,
    'filter_description'  => $description,
    'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
    'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
    'sort'                => $sort,
    'order'               => $order,
    'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit'               => $limit
);
```

Change only one line remove it or comment it.

```
$filter_data = array(
    'filter_name'         => $search,
    'filter_tag'          => $tag,
    /*'filter_description'  => $description,*/
    'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
    'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
    'sort'                => $sort,
    'order'               => $order,
    'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit'               => $limit
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this and be applied only to specific category ID,

In TWIG I do it like this,

```
{% if category_id=='69' %}
```

Thank you!